# Can I let spring-session used a standalone redis?

Tags: redis, spring-session

I have built up a redis server, I want to know whether I can make spring-session use the existed redis server instead of embed its redis-server?

Answer (score 2):

Yes Spring Session can and should use an existing Redis Server. This is the primary way to deploy to production. I have provided a few examples below:

**Spring Boot**

Taking the [Spring Boot Sample](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html5/guides/boot.html) and converting it to use an external Redis Server can be done by:

- Removing the [@EmbeddedRedisServer annotation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/1.0.1.RELEASE/samples/boot/src/main/java/sample/config/HttpSessionConfig.java#L22)
- [Configuring the Redis Server Location](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html5/guides/boot.html#boot-redis-configuration) For example, you might provide the following properties in your application.properties:

  spring.redis.host=example.com
  spring.redis.password=secret
  spring.redis.port=6379

**Other Samples**

The other samples are quite similar to use an external Redis instance. For example, to change the [httpsession sample](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html5/guides/httpsession.html) to use an external Redis:

- Remove [@EnableEmbeddedRedis](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/1.0.1.RELEASE/samples/httpsession/src/main/java/sample/Config.java#L25)
- Update your [RedisConnectionFactory Bean](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/1.0.1.RELEASE/samples/httpsession/src/main/java/sample/Config.java#L30) definition to point to your Redis server

For example:

```
@Bean
public JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    JedisConnectionFactory connection = new JedisConnectionFactory();
    connection.setPort(6379);
    connection.setHostName("example.com");
    connection.setPassword("secret");
    return connection;
}
```